# Self-signed certificate: DNSName components must begin with a letter

Tags: java, certificate, keytool, self-signed, wildcard-subdomain

Is there a way for java's keytool to generate self-signed certificate with a wildcard in SAN (Subject Alternative Name)? I'm using this command to generate keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -ext san=dns:*.example.com -keystore "path/to/my/keystore.jks" -validity 3650
```

But I get `IOException: DNSName components must begin with a letter`

Obviously, the problem is `*.example.com` in SAN, but I don't see other way of generating self-signed certificate for `example.com` subdomains.

According to [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/32818), it should be possible. Is it error in my syntax, bug in keytool, or I misunderstood something?

BTW, I'm using keytool from JDK 1.8 update 60

**EDIT** I managed to generate self-signed certificate for all `example.com` subdomains via keytool by specifying `CN=*.example.com`, and leaving SAN empty. Nonetheless, I'll leave Omikron's answer as accepted (since it's an actual answer and not a bypass of restrictions).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Keytool internally uses the class `sun.security.x509.DNSName` to check the input. DNSName enforces the syntax specified in [RFC 1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt). Quote from its Javadoc comment:

> The name MUST be in the "preferred name syntax," as specified by RFC
> 1034.

The preferred name syntax is:

```
<domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "
<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>
<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in
upper case and a through z in lower case
<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
```

So according to this syntax, domain names have to begin with a letter (A-Z, a-z).

Newer RFCs (e.g. [RFC 2181](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt), [RFC 1123](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)) are relaxing these restrictions, so this can be considered a bug in Java. There are already several related bug reports:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016345 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007706

So, the answer is no, there is currently no way to create a wildcard SAN extension with keytool.

But you could use [KeyStore Explorer](http://www.keystore-explorer.org) to do this. It is basically keytool with a GUI and does not enforce these restrictions.

---

UPDATE: This has been fixed in Java 15:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186143

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a big fan of SF and projects hosted there so I'll try with OpenSSL first... As a last resort I'll use KeyStore Explorer. Your answer is marked as accepted. Again, thank you.

Comment: @zkristic If you don't like SF, you can download it from GitHub: https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer/releases

Comment: @Omikron your final openjdk bug  link is actually also a link to keystore explorer, I assume it is unintentional and not meant to be misleading.

Comment: Yes, they even showcase fix in a dedicated blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/create-a-wildcard-with-san-certificate-and-sign-it-with-an-internal-ca-using-keytool-command