# Does Java Keytool allow SAN values to have wildcarded DNS names

Tags: java, x509certificate, keytool

According to RFC 2818 (section 3.1) RFC 2459 - It seems to be allowed to have a list of DNS name entries as part of SAN names and cover multiple domains:

```
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
  DNSName: *.i.mydomain.net
  DNSName: *.mydomain.net
]
```

Using Java `keytool` application - it doesn't seem to allow SAN entries to have wildcards in DNS names. Does anyone know whether I can use some tricks(!) to do this?

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827789/self-signed-certificate-dnsname-components-must-begin-with-a-letter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this problem in the past and worked around it by using OpenSSL to generate CSRs and only using keytool when I have to (importing & exporting certificates and keys).

EDIT: here's tl;dr of what I did

Have a `req.cfg` file that looks something like this:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @san
[san]
DNS.1 = *.mydomain.com
DNS.2 = mydomain.com
```

Then run this:

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -out keypair.csr -keyout keypair.key -config req.cfg
```

Now that you have your certificate signing request and private key, you can send your CSR to a CA or use OpenSSL to self-sign a certificate using the `keypair.csr` you just generated. However you do this, let's assume you get a cert that we'll call `mycert.crt`

You're pretty much done now but the tricky part is that you now need to convert your cert-key pair into a PKCS12 keystore before you attempting to import into your JKS keystore.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -name mycertname -in mycert.crt -inkey keypair.key -out keystore.p12
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias mycertname
```

Comment: I wish someone didn't say that :( but yes I came across this too. My problem is that my servers will only use these keys to exhange messages between themselves, so nothing from outside. Did you have to actually generate the CA for this too?

Comment: No I didn't need to actually generate the CA but you can certainly do that with OpenSSL too.

Comment: thanks - would you mind sharing your steps? I wanted to understand whether you simply converted the keys generated by openssl or exported them

Comment: I've updated my answer to walk you through how to do this

Comment: By any chance, do you know why it always complains "Unable to find distinguished_name in the config" - I am on windows the but the generation process shouldn't really rely on OS. I have added `distinguished_name` token but it seems it's still complaining.

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help you? https://superuser.com/a/1118045/212669