# Generating ssl certificate for tomcat with openssl creates "DSA" which firefox does not like

Tags: tomcat, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, tomcat9

I created a certificate request for tomcat by (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574633/does-java-keytool-allow-san-values-to-have-wildcarded-dns-names))

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -out req.csr -keyout keypair.key -config req.cfg
```

had the request signed by the authority and downloaded from the authority (MS Windows Server CA) as `base64` encoded, renamed from `cer` to `crt`. Then I configured `server.xml` https connector as:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           port="443"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           secure="true"
           scheme="https"
           SSLProtocol="TLSv1.0+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
           SSLCipherSuite="ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:!DSS"
           SSLHonorCipherOrder="true"
           SSLDisableCompression="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.home}/cert.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.home}/keypair.key"
           SSLCertificateChainFile="${catalina.home}/ca.crt"
           SSLPassword="password"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           maxThreads="200"
           acceptCount="100"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="49152"/>
```

When i access the site using https, firfox complains:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to dochazka.dt.local. Peer’s certificate has an invalid signature.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I found [here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO11342.html) that this is due to:

> This error will occur if DSA was used as signature algorithm when
>   generating  private key and CSR.

And since i have no idea what `DSA` is supposed to be, what to do to make it work as it should?
(note prefer not to use the `keytool` to generate the request)

Comment: Your openssl command created a RSA key not a DSA key so you are looking for the incorrect problem.  Your problem can't have anything to do with DSA keys.

Answer (score -1):

renamed from cer to crt might be your problem. The cer file may be a PKCS#7 file